# Как вывести данные из старой бд в новую бд postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Есть приложение (чужое) на rails с использованием бд postgresql. Когда делаю миграцию то данные не выводятся и к тому же файл schema.rb заполняется не совсем так как нужно. Как вывести все данные в новую базу данных если есть оригинальный файл schema.rb

Comment: А почему не через бэкап БД?

Comment: А для чего вы запускаете миграции, если у вас уже есть схема? Почему бы не сделать `db:schema:load`? Правда, надо понимать, что схема не содержит **данных**, она лишь **схема** для данных.

Comment: нада зделать backup чужой базы (pre-data + data + post-data), и потом restore в свою, типо всё